# IE is not loading all images

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, load

I have jQuery code that loads images with jQuery load method. It works perfectly in all other browsers, except in IE. I have about 10 images, but IE only loads few of those images and then stops loading. What could be causing this?

```
$(".image-container").each(function() { 

    ... some code here ...

    var img = $("img", this);

    $(img).load(function () {

        ... some code here ...

    });
});
```

Comment: Pull out fiddler and check the HTTP requests. What do they tell you/us?

Comment: I have hidden real images and I will create new images in JavaScript by taking src of images in HTML. Seems like when these real images are loaded, then they won't be ever loaded when I use load event to these newly creted images...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had an issue with I.E., where all browsers would load my images, except I.E.

I'm giving you this answer because while my issue wasn't with javascript, it had to do with images loading everywhere but not in I.E.

Turns out it was because some of the images were jpegs made by photoshop, that used a CYMK colorspace which IE don't support.

I used [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) to check the format (`identify -verbose`) and convert the images ( in my case something like `convert -profile CoatedFOGRA27.icc -profile sRGB.icm ...`

Again, I'm not sure this applies to your problem, but it doesn't hurt to check the format of your images. I hope it's useful.

Comment: I found out that those images were already loaded, so load event didnt catch those. So I had to add ready event to catch those already laoded images

Comment: +1 wish I could vote this like 5x since IE just did this to me and I had absolutely no idea what was going on since other browsers (and IE9) worked fine.